# can I group components in methods when working with swing?

Tags: java, swing, oop

I feel that at times it is more convenient for me to group components in methods in order to make my code more organized. This is so because some components may have different functionality, or may get too long, for example a menu, the menu can have menu items, each menu item at the same time can have more sub items and so on. So is it okay to organize components in methods? what are the advantages or disadvantages? I mean like this:

```
 public class MyGUI{



    public myGUI(){

       registerEvents();
       setupGUI();

     }

     public void createTextEditor(){
         ....
        }

        public void createAccountActivationPanel(){
         ...
        }

        public void createAddButton(){
        .....
        }

        public void createRemoveButton(){
        ....
        }


        public void createMenu()
        ...
        }


        public void createLabels() {
        .....
        }

        public void setupGui() {
         createTextEditor();
         createAccountActivationPanel();
         createRemoveButton();
         createAddButton();

         //and then proceed with more stuff here

         ......
        }


        public void registerEvents() {


          .....


        }
   }
```

Comment: Generally speaking yes, you can.  As you said, the advantage is that you can focus on the immediate requirements of the UI that the method is responsible for.  One of the disadvantages (it's also and advantage) is that it can be difficult to expand in the future.  If the design is not just right, you can spend a lot of time trying to "undo" certain sections and trying to rebuild them.  So, while I would encourage you to break down the UI creation like this, I would also encourage you to try and think about how you might like to modify these UI's in the future...

Comment: Thank you MadProgramemr, would it perhaps be best to put everything on the constructor? or on a single setUp() method? I feel that by doing so, the code gets very disorganized and then if a hypothetical setup method does many different things at once it is not in line with what I have learned in terms of good oop practices. In addition I thought that by grouping in methods I can call them when I need them, that is, I can achieve certain modularity, and not not if they are not necessary, which at the same time can also make the program faster can it not?

Comment: I don't think it will make your program run faster, but it could make it more customisable in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Organizing your code and creating helper methods is always a good thing.

Some tips:

- the **helper methods should be `private`**, there's no need to access those from outside your class
- check which methods are supposed to be called only *once* (for example: `setupGui()`). When these methods are called, check and throw an Exception if it has been called before (using an instance variable such as `boolean initialized`).
- consider creating **factory methods that produce and return something** (a widget, or even a subcomponent consisting of other widgets). 
  Example: `createAddButton()` should return a button, and the caller of the method should decide where the button is to be added, not the factory method.
- If possible, make your factory method `static` (this only works when you don't need to access any instance variables or instance methods). This reduces complexity and side effects, and allows to externalize factory methods into reusable factory classes.
- Consider making generic, **reusable components** when you need them often (example: a list or table with add/edit/remove actions)